# Json Clearing the file object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am facing one issue.

i need pass some info along with one file to controller using Ajax call.

Model as follows:

```
public class PersonModel
    {
        [Display(Name ="Full Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Email Id")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Upload Photo")]
        [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller as follows:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(PersonModel P)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

view :

```
@model FileCurdoperation.Models.PersonModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "blogform", id = "blogform" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>PersonModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Photo, new { type = "file",@class = "form-control" })*@
                <input type="file" id="Photo" name="Photo" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="UpdateDetails();" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<script>
    function UpdateDetails() {
        debugger;
        var image = $('#Photo').get('0').files[0];
        var param = { "Name": $('#Name').val().trim(), "email": $('#email').val().trim(), "Photo": $('#Photo').get('0').files[0] };
         param = JSON.stringify(param);
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/Employee/Index",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: param,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (response) {
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

I need to pass Name, email and Photo to the controller.

if the button type is submit, it works as expected.

but My requirement is that i should use Ajax call.

param = JSON.stringify(param);

in this line file getting clear.

[image]

After converting json

[image]

[image]

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FormData` To Send The data

```
function UpdateDetails() {
    var file_data = $('#Photo').get('0').files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("Photo", file_data);
    fd.append("email", $('#email').val().trim());
    fd.append("Name", $('#Name').val().trim());
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Test",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:fd,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) for all four ways to submit data, and to upload files